# Change class path to launch vm

Tags: linux, junit, virtual-machine, jdi

First of all I am working on linux :) I am trying to launch a VM using JDI. I need to change the arguments in a connector. The connector is a  LaunchingConnector connector from Bootstrap.virtualMachineManager().
the code is something like this:

```
    for (LaunchingConnector connector : Bootstrap.virtualMachineManager().
       launchingConnectors()) {
        if (connector.name().equals("com.sun.jdi.CommandLineLaunch")) {
           Map<String, Connector.Argument> map = connector.defaultArguments();

           StringArgument arg = (StringArgument) map.get("main");
           arg.setValue(mainClass); //junit core

           arg = (StringArgument) map.get("options");
           arg.setValue(classpath);
```

I am trying to change the classpath so that it looks for the JUnit core I tell it so the new class path is "../../lib/junit-4.6.jar" and the class is "org.junit.runner.JUnitCore"

When I try and run

```
    VirtualMachine vm = connector.launch(map);
```

it throws a VMStartException because it tries to run a command like this:

```
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java ../../lib/junit-4.6.jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=CIS-Visitor:57881,suspend=y org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

it is not changing the classpath and in the end it does not return a vm. Can anyone tell me a way to change this? I would also like to take out the -Xdebug from the command and change the port number.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the classpath used to launch the machine is not automatically inherited by the new VM that you create. However, it looks like if you use environment variables to define the classpath instead, they are inherited. See [Can't run JDI trace example: Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661122/cant-run-jdi-trace-example-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class/16929194#16929194) for a similar issue.